# "Coercing LHS to a list" Error in doing iterative functions with tables

Tags: r

I was having error in `for` loop with tables in r. So basically I have 3 tables: `H_grouped`, `SA_grouped`, and `NW_grouped`. I want to create a new column in each of them so I tried doing this:

```
all_tables = c(H_grouped, SA_grouped, NW_grouped)

for (i in all_tables){
  i$newcol = 0
}
```

But I'm getting this error message:

> In `i$newcol <- 0`: Coercing LHS to a list

Answer (score 1):

Instead of doing

```
all_tables = c(H_grouped, SA_grouped, NW_grouped)
```

you should use

```
all_tables <- list(H_grouped, SA_grouped, NW_grouped)
```

Then, you can assign new columns to the dataframe

```
for (i in length(all_tables)){
  all_tables[[i]]$newcol <- 0
}
```